# Connection closed by target host before receiving the request wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, esb

I am getting this "Connection closed by target host before receiving the request" due this first system get time out. 
But the problem is that we are getting the proper response from second system.
just provide one major problem
after getting the response from second system we are also getting the one more response.
that i am not able to understand.

the arch is 
First System ---- > ESB ---->> second system
response
Second system ---->> ESB then we are going the clone
1. send response to first system
2. send request to DSS to log the request.

can you please help in this...
i am using wso2 esb 4.8.1 and i can not change right now it in production.

Regards,
Shachindra Singh

Comment: not clear what you are asking here

Comment: Connection closed by target host before receiving the request ..

Comment: it is just a warn right?

Comment: when we got the request in my proxy , i called on internal API that send the request to second system as soon as i got the response. i just create the clone and first will response back to calling system and second clone call DSS to log the response. but what i observer that in some senerio i am getting 2 response first i proper and second blank.. just after that i am getting the above error

Comment: i am not able to attached logs

Comment: you can copy paste full log in to the question

Comment: not able to past log.. can you please send your mail id..or any id in that i can share you the detail...

Comment: can you send the question with logs to dev@wso2.org mailing list?

Comment: hi shared the detail

Comment: I cannot see the question in malining list

Answer (score 1):

As you explained in your question, it seems connection between the client and the server has timed out. These kind of lagging can be happen due to the back-end slowness or the ESB server contention. Hence Increasing time out settings could be solve this problem.

By default the ESB closes the connection after 60 seconds. So even you increased the client(which send the request)the timeout the problem will not solve.

For your information in WSO2 ESB can set three types of timeouts:

1. socket timeout - This parameter will decide on the timeout which a
   particular http request is waiting for a response.
2. endpoint timeout - This will help to configure timeout per endpoint.
3. synapse global timeout - This will decide the maximum time that a
   callback is waiting in the ESB for a response for a particular
   request.

Please refer below links [1], [2] to find more detailed information about WSO2 ESB Error Handling. Hopefully it will help you to solve the problem.

[1] http://soatutorials.blogspot.com/2015/06/wso2-esb-error-handling-tutorial-part-i.html

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Performance+Tuning

Cheers.